# What are the alternate ways to find next().next() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the css attribute of element which is just next to next of selector.

I have used this syntax

```
$('#hide').next().next().css('display', 'block');
```

but i think there can be another better approach can be use like `find()` or `eq()`

```
<li class="expandable">
    <div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea"></div>
    <div id="hide" class="hide"></div>
    <a href="#" class=""> <strong>Stitched</strong> </a>

    <ul style="display: none;" id="hi">
        <li> <a href="#"> Hand Block Print </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Designer </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="last"> <a href="#"> Screen Printed </a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try

```
  $('#hide').nextAll().eq(1).css('display', 'block');
```

[`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) returns *all* the next elements, [`eq(1)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) returns the second one amongst them.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, worked for me.

If nextAll() returns all the next elements, then selects the one you want, is this code less efficient than simply selecting the .next().next() element?  In other words, if there are 1,000 elements on the page, should you avoid using this?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `.siblings` selector:

```
$('#hide').siblings("ul").css('display', 'block');
```

Or by index:

```
$('#hide').siblings("ul").eq(0).css('display', 'block');
```

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DUBFU/)

Comment: The second example really makes no sense. If you know the ID of the element you want then you should just select it directly.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that's a very good point, brain was elsewhere when I was writing that...